# Methods to show polynomials are irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would like to show that $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. What are my standard lines of attack to solve this problem? Typically I go to Eistenstein, but it does not apply to this polynomial (I believe). I'm familiar also with Gauss' lemma, are there other theoretical tools I can use to prove this?

Edit: Rational root test?

Comment: Yes, in this case the Rational Roots test works, as with any other polynomial of degree three or less (why?) .

Comment: Eisenstein is a terrible way to handle such problems in general: most irreducible polynomials are not Eisenstein with respect to any prime, even under a change of variables $x \mapsto x+c$. If you want to *construct* an irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ then use Eisenstein, but if you want to check something that is *given to you* is irreducible, then unless the example is rigged it is unlikely to be settled using Eisenstein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as your polynomial is degree $3 (\dagger)$, the rational root test is well-suited to the task. (We are looking to show irreduciblity over $\mathbb Q$, a.k.a. the rationals, after all!)

$(\dagger)$ A degree-$3$ polynomial in $\mathbb Q$, if reducible, must have a rational root, since any reducible polynomial in $\mathbb {Q}[x]$ must factor into a product of at least one *linear factor* and a quadratic, (though it may reduce to a product of three linear factors). This isn't necessarily the case for polynomials of greater degree.

Comment: I'm sorry, it sounds like it should be immediately clear, but why does degree 3 imply to use the Rational Root test?
Edit: or put differently, do I know to not use it for degree 4?

Comment: The [rational root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is decisive for degree 2 or degree 3 polynomials, with respect to decisions of irreducibility: no rational roots $\iff$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q$...that's all.

Comment: @user80719 A 4th-degree polynomial might be reducible even if it has no rational roots.  Consider for example $x^4-4$, which is reducible over $\Bbb Q$ (as $(x^2-2)(x^2+2)$, obviously), but which has no rational roots. But a reducible 2nd- or 3rd-degree polynomial must have a linear factor, and therefore has a rational root.

Comment: @MJD Thank you, the requiring a linear factor explains it well.

Comment: A polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 3 must have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$ if it is reducible, as any reducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ must factor into a product of a linear factor and a quadratic (it may yet reduce further, but ANY reducible cubic will factor as such). A polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ can be factored as $f(x) = (x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a root of of $f(x)$ and $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. As MJD said, this may not be true if $\deg(f(x)) \geq 4$; a reducible degree 4 polynomial may factor as a product of quadratics.

Comment: @amWhy: Gets a thumbs up. +1